# Do I have to write my own Exceptions? - Java

Tags: java, exception

I am learning to program in Java at the moment.

Often I come across exceptions which I want to handle properly. Regardinging this I ask myself if I have to create my own Exceptions when I want to throw a valid Exception.

I'm aware that there are already plenty of Java-Exceptions used in the API which I could use (obviously rarely meeting the exact case I want to express).

I could imagine that this is normal, but creating an own exception seems really costly to me for the result that it brings.

How is this done generally in programming? Is it normal to create exception for every case?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why does creating your own exception class seem costly to you?

Comment: Creating an extra class and extending it from Exception, write a constructor for it etc. - But this is the reason I ask, I am not at the point yet where I can judge if it really is costly or not - at the moment it just feels like that :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its well supported in Java and fairly easy to implement. The cost is nominal when compared to the benefit of understanding unwanted conditions that occur.

Create a class the extends Exception class.

```
public class SampleException extends Exception{

  private String message;

  public SampleException() {
  }

  public SampleException(String message) {
    this.message = message;
  }

  public String getMessage() {
    return this.message;
  }
}
```

To throw custom exception:

```
throw new SampleException("Something happen!!!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are used to help you see where in your program an error has occurred. Sometimes you might want to have a custom exception to display a message to the end user stating that something was unexpected.

For example if the user was entering information into a text field and they entered a letter instead of a number in the Zip Code field it may be you decision to show them a message and allowing them to try again.

Creating custom exceptions are very easy to do. All exceptions are sub-classes from the Exception class, so all you need to do is extend Exception within your CustomException class.

What it comes down to -- what is your design decision for having exceptions for everything. If you can make a valid argument for them, go for it.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you want the user end to see. You definitely do not want end user to see an exception that is thrown by a function that was not wrapped with a try and catch. That could simply throw stack errors and stop the application. You should wrap your methods within try and catch.

What I generally do is, build up an XML file that hosts the errors and based on matches, I display a friendly error, that is if the users are not advanced enough to understand the errors, which is the case most of the time.